# Python list to dictionary

Tags: python

I have two list one with the label and the other data. for example

> label = ["first","second"]
>   list = [[1,2],[11,22]]

I need the result to be a list of dictionary

> [ {
>       "first" : 1,
>       "second" : 2,
>      },
>      {
>       "first" : 11,
>       "second" : 22,
>      }
>   ]

Is there a simple way to do that. Note the label and list might vary, but number of entry remain the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> label = ["first","second"]
>>> lists = [[1,2],[11,22]]
>>> [dict(zip(label, l)) for l in lists]
[{'second': 2, 'first': 1}, {'second': 22, 'first': 11}]
```

Comment: @Series8217: Guess I was lucky do be one of the first ones to see it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> [dict(zip(label, e)) for e in list]
[{'second': 2, 'first': 1}, {'second': 22, 'first': 11}]
```